# Self signed certificate - what domain? (Apache, Windows)

Tags: windows, domain, certificate

I need to create SSL access to my logon page, accessed mostly via Intranet but possibly via Internet too. The server is Apache on Windows XP Proff (or Win 2003 server).

I have created my certificate using:

```
openssl req -new -out server.csr
```

which asks for "Common Name" which is supposed to be the fully-qualified domain name associated with this certificate.
Just for tests, I entered there a string - my company name (not a domain), entered the created certificate into the Windows certificate manager, but then Chrome is complaining "This is probably not the site you are looking for!", pointing out the difference between the site domain and the certificate domain (the certificate is seen and used properly).

Questions:

1. What domain should I enter into "Common Name", for my Intranet (local network) server? So far I have no domains, just IP addresses.
2. Is it possible to have one certificate for a server accessed both:

   - from Intranet
   - from Internet?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the name of the box, which is mapped to IP in `/etc/hosts` or [local] DNS (use command `dig -x addr`, where `addr` is the IP of your box on the intranet to determine its name).

You should ensure that the name you're using in the certificate matches exactly to box name on the intranet/internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it out. Forgot about the /etc/hosts...  But let me ask 2 more things:  1) dig seems to be a linux command? I am working on Windows. 2) Is /etc/hosts for intranet, internet or both?   Thanks.

Comment: 1) `dig(1)` is a unix counterpart of `nslookup(1)`. 2) `/etc/hosts` is for intranet only. DNS is used for internets.

Comment: there is an excellent port of dig for windows [here](http://members.shaw.ca/nicholas.fong/dig/)